# Why does git rerere refuse to resolve some conflicts?

Tags: git, git-rerere

I'm trying to use git-rerere, but it just refuses to resolve some conflicts, even when repeating the exact same merge.   I can't figure out what's so special about these conflicts or why it is skipping them.   Rerere doesn't seem to have any verbose mode or any way of explaining why it resolves certain conflicts and not others.

What sort of conditions would cause rerere to skip over a conflict?

Note: it says it's recording my conflicts, but it just skips over them when it's time to merge.

Comment: Just speculating here... Is it possible you've already provided 2 (conflicting) resolutions of the same conflict?  Maybe there are 2 resolutions and rerere doesn't know which one to use.